# Using array of classes in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Using SASS/SCSS. I have the following:

```
body:not(.sessions):not(.registrations):not(.home):not(.posts.new) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}
```

This is not readable at all. How do I refactor this by using an array of classes:

```
$full-page-classes: .sessions .registrations .home .posts.new
```

Comment: body:not(.sessions):not(.registrations):not(.home):not(.posts.new)  It's a native selector,You want to ask with sass selector can loop splice?

Comment: @多一点点爱 Yes, how can I refactor this in SASS?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.I'll keep an eye on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to use the *array* like this:

```
$full-page-classes: '.sessions', '.registrations', '.home', '.posts.new';

@each $page-class in $full-page-classes {
  body:not(#{$page-class}) {
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
body:not(.sessions) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

body:not(.registrations) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

body:not(.home) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

body:not(.posts.new) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}
```

You can try it on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

---

Update:

If you want to generate *inline* CSS, you can try this:

```
$full-page-classes: '.sessions', '.registrations', '.home', '.posts.new';

$temp: '';

@each $page-class in $full-page-classes {
  $temp: $temp + ':not(#{$page-class})';
}

@each $item in $temp {
  body#{$item} {
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
body:not(.sessions):not(.registrations):not(.home):not(.posts.new) {
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}
```

---

Update 2:

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}

$full-page-classes: ' .sessions, .registrations, .home, .posts.new,';

@each $x in str-replace(str-replace($full-page-classes, ' ', ':not('), ',', ')') {
  body#{$x} {
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }
}
```

Reference: [str-replace function](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/)

Comment: Thanks, but this generates multiple `body`, which results in bigger compiled CSS file, when they could have been joined as one statement.

Comment: That really splices the selector,I think this method will work.But can you encapsulate a function as a direct call?It's even more complicated than the native selector.

Comment: @多一点点爱 I can only think about defining a function as a library for all sass/scss files, just like my update 2.